# Find a formula in terms of k for the entries of $A^k$, where A is the diagonalizable matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find a formula in terms of k for the entries of $A^k$, where A is the diagonalizable matrix
This is my 2x2 matrix (sorry for formatting):

[$-5$ $8$]

[$-4$ $7$]

I've tried this question a million times and I always get the answer the wrong. To start off, I found my eigenvalues and eigenvectors which are: eigenvalue1: -1 eigenvalue2: 3, eigenvector1: (1,1), (2,1).

Can someone please show me a step by step without ommitting any calculations? I have the answer, but I do not know how to arrive at it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We write the Jordan Normal Form (that is, write it as a diagonal matrix) as:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}-5 & 8\\-4 & 7\end{bmatrix} = PJP^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 &1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1& 0\\0 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\-1& 2\end{bmatrix}$$

Now

$$A^k = PJ^kP^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\1 &1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}(-1)^k& 0\\0 & (3)^k\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\-1& 2\end{bmatrix}$$

You can multiply this out as:

$$A^k = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 (-1)^k-3^k & -2 (-1)^k+2\ 3^k \\
 (-1)^k-3^k & -(-1)^k+2\ 3^k \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: $P P^{-1} \neq I$ here...

Comment: Yes, that is what I got... except I forgot to put the exponent k in.. how do I compute the last part though? That's the calculation I am having trouble with as noobish as it may sound

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks, you've been a great help!