# Determining matrix of similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PBP^{-1}$.

If the two matrices are similar, how do you find $P$?

Comment: how do you know they are similar? are you given two similar matrices $A,B$ and told to find $P?$

Comment: @abel Yes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: but if $P$ is a solution so is $PQ,$ for any invertible matrix $Q.$ this means your problem has infinitely many solutions unless you put some more constraints on $P.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P$ is made up of the columns of eigenvectors for each eigenvalue.

See [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Example).

You can find many examples on MSE, for example: [Find a formula in terms of k for the entries of Ak, where A is the diagonalizable matrix:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731808/find-a-formula-in-terms-of-k-for-the-entries-of-ak-where-a-is-the-diagonalizabl)

Note: This answer assumes that A is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Every matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ has a Jordan form, and there is an algortithm to construct a matrix $M$ such that $J = M^{-1} A M$. If $A$ and $B$ are similar they have the same Jordan form. Hence we got so far
$$ J = M^{-1} A M \ , \qquad J = N^{-1} B N $$
where we know $M$ and $N$ (by finding a basis of generalized eigenvectors, the "Jordanizing basis". By equating these two expressions we get
$$ A = M N^{-1} B N M^{-1} = (NM^{-1})^{-1} B (NM^{-1}) $$
and thus $P = NM^{-1}$.

If the problem is defined over $\mathbb{R}$ one need to show that $P$ can be chosen such that all its coefficients are real.